# ¿Mandar dato de una columna de un grid view de un formulario a un combo box de otro formulario?

Tags: c#, combobox, gridview

Necesito enviar el valor de una columna en una fila seleccionada al dar clic en un botón a un combobox en otro formulario. Así esta mi codigo actual.

Esto en el primer form.

```
    private void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (dgvLibros.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        {
            frmNuevoLibro NuevoLibro = new frmNuevoLibro();
            
            NuevoLibro.txtClaveLibro.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            NuevoLibro.cboRecibidoDe.SelectedItem= 
            dgvLibros.CurrentRow.Cells["Recibido de"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Aqui el error que se me presenta es que no se manda nada, mi combo se queda como valor seleccionado (-SELECCIONAR-), que es el valor que tiene por default. Otro punto importante es que los datos del combo los obtengo de base de datos a través de un procedimiento almacenado.

```
    private void LlenarCbo()
    {
        clsCNLibros Libros = new clsCNLibros();
        cboRecibidoDe.DataSource = Libros.ListarRecibido();
        cboRecibidoDe.DisplayMember = "Nombre";
        cboRecibidoDe.ValueMember = "IdRecibido";
    }
```

Para mostrar los datos del libro donde va incluido la columna recibido de tambien utilizo un procedimiento almacenado que es algo asi.

```
     ALTER proc [dbo].[MostrarLibros]
     as
     select  Estado, IdLibro as [Clave del Libro], RecibidoDe.Nombre as [Recibido de], 
     Clasificacion, ISBN, NoActivo, Titulo, Autor, Cs, Editorial, Año, Ejemplares, 
     FechaRecibido as [Fecha recibido], Foto from Libros
     inner join RecibidoDe on Libros.IdRecibido=RecibidoDe.IdRecibido
```

Comment: La pantalla donde queres recibir los datos ya esta abierta o es nueva?

Comment: Se abre al dar clic en el boton de Editar, en esa parte no puse el codigo completo porque son mas campos y quise poner solo el codigo relevante, pero si tiene mas codigo primero mando toda la informacion a los campos y despues muestro el formulario, con textbox si funciona pero con el combo no.

Answer (score 0):

El error en tu código parece radicar en que estas queriendo asignar un valor `string` la variable `SelectedItem` del combo  `NuevoLibro.cboRecibidoDe` y aunque no lo dices en tú pregunta, es casi seguro que el tipo de datos del campo "IdRecibido" que es el que asignas a la propiedad `ValueMember` del combo  `NuevoLibro.cboRecibidoDe` no es de tipo `string`, si ese es le caso, la siguiente linea:

```
NuevoLibro.cboRecibidoDe.SelectedItem=   dgvLibros.CurrentRow.Cells["Recibido de"].Value.ToString();
```

No asignaría ningún valor pues lo tipos no coinciden,

Prueba hacer lo siguiente.

```
private void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (dgvLibros.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
    {
        frmNuevoLibro NuevoLibro = new frmNuevoLibro();
        
        NuevoLibro.txtClaveLibro.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        //Asigna el valor almacenado, sin convertir a string
        NuevoLibro.cboRecibidoDe.SelectedItem= 
        dgvLibros.CurrentRow.Cells["Recibido de"].Value;
    }
}
```

Ten en cuenta además verificar que la columna `"Recibido de"` contiene los datos del campo `"IdRecibido"` si no tampoco funcionará la asignación.